# Keras get optimal AUC threshold for a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, statistics

I have trained a binary classifier with Keras. This is the model definition:

```
model_binary = Sequential()
model_binary.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',input_shape=(7,)))
model_binary.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_binary.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model_binary.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_binary.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model_binary.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_binary.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

This is the training code:

```
model_binary.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics [tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')])
model_binary.fit(binary_train_data, binary_train_labels, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_split=0.1)


Epoch 1/10
507/507 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4017 - auc: 0.5965 - val_loss: 0.2997 - val_auc: 0.8977
Epoch 2/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3354 - auc: 0.7387 - val_loss: 0.2729 - val_auc: 0.9019
Epoch 3/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3167 - auc: 0.7837 - val_loss: 0.2623 - val_auc: 0.9021
Epoch 4/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3072 - auc: 0.8057 - val_loss: 0.2551 - val_auc: 0.9003
Epoch 5/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2948 - auc: 0.8298 - val_loss: 0.2507 - val_auc: 0.9033
Epoch 6/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2921 - auc: 0.8355 - val_loss: 0.2489 - val_auc: 0.9005
Epoch 7/10
507/507 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2867 - auc: 0.8431 - val_loss: 0.2465 - val_auc: 0.9016
Epoch 8/10
507/507 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2865 - auc: 0.8434 - val_loss: 0.2460 - val_auc: 0.9017
Epoch 9/10
507/507 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2813 - auc: 0.8493 - val_loss: 0.2452 - val_auc: 0.9030
Epoch 10/10
507/507 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2773 - auc: 0.8560 - val_loss: 0.2441 - val_auc: 0.9029
```

The dataset is skewed. There are 87% positive samples and 13% negative samples. Based on `val_auc`  it seems the model is pretty decent. Now the question is how to use this model for prediction.

When I pass `binary_train_data` to the binary model, the lowest output score is around `0.6` but in a balanced dataset, the cutoff threshold for sigmoid activation is `0.5`. My question is given data `x`, how can I find the model's predicted class of `x`, and also how can I get the optimal threshold for classification that Keras has found?

```
prediction=model_binary(binary_train_data).numpy()
print(np.amin(prediction))

0.5979678
```

Thanks.

P.S: train_labels is nd-array of shape `N` of 0 and 1s.

Comment: I guess by " the model's predicted class of x" you mean logits fed to final "sigmoid" activation?

Comment: I want to see which of the 0 or 1 class does the model assign to x? When using the sigmoid and binary entropy function, if the sigmoid output is greater than 0.5 then x is classified as 1 and if the output is less than 0.5 then x is classified as 0.
I wanted to see what is the analogy here since I used AUC as a metric and no longer there is a sigmoid output lesser than 0.5, even for 0 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes | points 1 and 2 are optional readings**

1. Since you have a skewed dataset, the `AUC` metric with the `PR` curve might be more insightful. Please feel free to see the paper entitled "The Precision-Recall Plot Is More Informative than the ROC Plot When Evaluating Binary Classifiers on Imbalanced Datasets" by Saito and Rehmsmeier (2015),  *DOI:10.1371/journal.pone.0118432*.
2. The default curve of AUC in TensorFlow is currently `ROC`. For more reading please refer to the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC).
3. Regarding the following:

> how can I find the model's predicted class of x

please note that model just tries to minimize the loss and outputs a probability distribution for a given example. The model does not explicitly assign any example to any of the classes. In the case of your binary classification, the Sigmoid activation outputs a number between 0 and 1. The one who uses the model can then determine an appropriate threshold/cutoff for classification.

4. To find the optimal threshold, you can evaluate your model for various thresholds aiming at, for example, finding the highest F1 score. The advantage of F1 score is that it is a single metric that already takes into account both recall and precision metrics (for a given threshold). However, you can plot the PR curve and manually specify the best recall/precision (based on your application requirements). From there, you can find the corresponding threshold.